# Ruby on Rails duplicate column name: user_id: ALTER TABLE "articles" ADD "user_id" integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i keep getting error message: -- add_column(:articles, :user_id, :integer)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: user_id: ALTER TABLE "articles" ADD "user_id" integer

here are All the migration i made:

```
 class AddUserIdToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :articles, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

---

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
        t.string :username
        t.string :email
        t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
class AddDescriptionToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :articles, :description, :text
    add_column :articles, :created_at, :datetime
    add_column :articles, :updated_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

---

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title
    end
  end
end
```

---

Answer (score 3):

The error is on

```
class AddUserIdToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :articles, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Because the column `user_id` already exists on the table `articles`

You can verify by changing the code to:

```
class AddUserIdToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    unless column_exists? :articles, :user_id
      add_column :articles, :user_id, :integer
    end
  end
end
```

But I don't advice it, the column should not be there at the first place, or you are just trying to add a column that is already there.

BTW, I would advice to add an index to your foreign keys, like `user_id`

Comment: @MikeShasaco if my answer helped you, feel free to give me a vote and mark my answer as accepted, thats the way stackoverflow works ;)